# Document ID feature still scheduled to be completed by an automated process?

Tags: document-library, document-id

In SharePoint 2013, I just added a new site collection. I activated the Document ID feature. I set the Document ID settings. I went to Central Admin and started the Document ID enable/disable job.

I can see that the job ran for all of my previously existing site collections, but not on my new site collection.

And when I go back to Document ID Settings, it says

> Configuration of the Document ID feature is scheduled to be completed by an automated process.

These things must be connected - the Timer Job is not running on this Site Collection and the message.

Why didn't the Document ID enable/disable job run on this site collection? Did I miss a step?

Comment: The Document ID enable/disable job has a web application scope so the job history is only reported for that scope. What do you mean by "I can see that the job [did not run] on my new site collection"?

Answer (score 2):

There are two timer jobs related to the config and assignment of Document IDs:

1. Document ID enable/disable job (on my farm scheduled for 9:30PM daily)
2. Document ID assignment job (on my farm scheduled for 10:00PM daily)

Suggest that you run the second one as well, in order.

On your SP2013 farm do the following:

1. Created a new site collection using Team Site template
2. Enabled the Document ID feature
3. Verified that the above msg was displayed in the Document ID Settings
4. Wait 30 min for the work item to enable the feature to run.
5. Ran the first timer job, Document ID enable/disable job, on the parent web application
6. Verified that the above msg was still displayed in the Document ID Settings
7. Ran the second timer job, Document ID assignment job, on the parent web application
8. Verified that the above msg was no longer present in the Document ID Settings
9. Uploaded a document to the Shared Documents library and verified that it has a document ID assigned

Comment: This is a great answer, but it needs the bit of extra info from Paul's answer: Running these timer jobs only works >30min after the Document ID feature has been enabled.

Answer (score 1):

A work item is created after you enable the Document ID Service feature. That work item is scheduled to be process after 30 minutes from the activation of the feature. You can run timer jobs as many times as you want the but nothing will happen for the first 30 minutes.

You can check when a scheduled work item will be processed by running the following query on the Content Database:

```
declare @enable uniqueidentifier
set @enable = cast(’749FED41-4F86-4277-8ECE-289FBF18884F’ as uniqueidentifier)
select * from [dbo].[ScheduledWorkItems] where [Type] = @enable
```

749FED41-4F86-4277-8ECE-289FBF18884F is the ID of the Document ID enable / disable timer job.

More information on how that works [here](http://sharepointbitsandbytes.com/2015/03/web-application-document-id/).